# Alamofire JSON encoding (request parameters) failed only at the time of AppStore review. diffrent from issues in stack overflow

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I test this thing many time in many devices with different ios versions but always succeeded to make API call. Also test with testflight build and got success for same request params.

Only at the time of App store review I got the error **"JSON could not be serialized because of error:\nThe data couldnâ€™t be read because it isnâ€™t in the correct format."**

for a correct formatted **"requestParameter": {"device_token": "cBXIAfxpEpk:APA91bH8AZYHqMniP5oGNuHT7czD-wHm_ioE-th1_LkN3_w5w_KUa5grT6Ff73D8j9Kn-xONeK4ytT8ZSfVssG9mf4KwJzhY7WdoSxUHxLKNxyGMI0g9ieyuyF25Pi3KwFXDIQmawmow", "time_zone": "America/Los_Angeles", "device_type": "ios", "username": "demo", "password": "password", "location": "37.452728,-121.940140"}**

*these are the information i got from firebase files*

I am sure its not for response because I also verified with backend but there is no log fired at that time , So its unable to make request from mobile side.

**here is my API method**

```
func serviceCall(withPath path:String, withData param:[String:Any], withCompletionHandler completion:@escaping (AnyObject?) -> Void){
    let requestURL = String(format: "%@%@", BaseURL, path)
    let manager = Alamofire.SessionManager.default

    manager.session.configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 40

    manager.request(requestURL, method: .post, parameters: param, encoding: URLEncoding.methodDependent, headers: nil).responseJSON { (responseJson) in
        print("Response 10: \(responseJson)")

        if ((responseJson.result.value != nil)){
           // store details to firebase

        } else {
           // store details to firebase
        }
    }
}
```

please help me out already rejected by app store for many times :(

Thank you in advance !!

Comment: Did you try your app with TestFlight build?

Comment: Please check your API response, there is some issue with your json response, can you please share your API response?

Comment: Hi, @cz I test with test flight build did not found this issue.

Comment: hi, @Khush i checked with my back end team , this request from app store review did not hit in there log, So I think its a problem in mobile side request parameter serialization ....!